# Crystal filter impedance matching

Tags: rf, filter, radio, crystal

I have a quite basic question about crystal filter impedance termination. 
F.e. ECS-45K20A 45Mhz IF filter - it has specified terminating impedance 910 Ohm / 2.5p. 
https://pl.mouser.com/datasheet/2/122/mono%20crystal%20filters-309914.pdf

According to Murata application note impedance matching is described as resistor / capacitor combination and it shows effects of incorrect match.
https://www.murata.com/en-sg/products/filter/crystalfil/matching

1) As I understand - that values (refering to Murata a.n.) are correct for 50 Ohm source and load. How impedance terminator should be defined in 2-3 series connection?

2) It is necessary calculate values if load or source have impedance other than 50 Ohm?

Thanks for any answers.

Comment: At 45pF, you need a real load of 910 ohm, and quadrature load of 2.5pF. Given 1pF at 1GHz is --J159ohm, then 2.5pF at 1GHz is 159/2.5 = -J60 ohms. And at any frequency, to have only 2.5pF Cload will require serious attention of the mechanical configuration, the PCB payout, avoiding GND PLANE under the filter's output pin, and perhaps bootstrapping of any active circuit following the filter.

Answer (score 0):

> ECS-45K20A 45MHz IF filter - it has specified terminating impedance 910 Ohm / 2.5pF

Good question on assumption #1 which leads to #2.

*Rt tolerance animation* on web shows 50 Ohm equip. + 1500 rather than +1450=1500 Ohm.   Yet datasheet does not show that.

So, I assume **Rt includes 50 Ohms or any other voltage source or load value.**

[image]

Since the filter has internal impedance of 910 Ohms, an interstage R is not needed, just C to tune up the skirts e.g. BW @ -15 dB

Note dot orientation.